# Can inject operation but can't preapply operation, returns 400

Tags: operation, python

I can inject an operation but can't preapply an operation, it returns 400.

[image]

I checked the body's format and it's OK. Why does this rpc return 400? I can inject the operation.

Answer (score 2):

The preapply/operations endpoint requires an array of operations to be [submitted](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/rpc.html#post-block-id-helpers-preapply-operations).

Just wrap your call around square brackets and it should work. This is how it's [done in eztz.](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/src/main.js#L603)